# How can I resize the Applications menu item in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux, and in the top left corner of my screen there's an Applications menu, with items like this:

```
01 - Info...
02 - Vul...
03 - We...
```

How can I enlarge the menu, so that the entire folder names would fit?

I've found the file containing all the menu items (`/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/kali-applications.menu`), but there seems to be no way to edit the width, or preferably make it auto-fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered on [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387843/how-can-i-resize-the-applications-menu-item-in-gnome). This was the answer:

edit:

```
'/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js'
```

and replace:

```
this.categoriesBox.box.width = 300;
```

by:

```
this.mainBox.box.width = 950;
this.categoriesBox.box.width = 500;
```